# Gerar CSV com resultados lado a lado no PHP

Tags: php, csv

Estou tentando obter resultados comparativos em um *CSV* gerado no *php* mas não consigo empilhar lado a lado da maneira que ilustra o **RESULTADO ESPERADO** da imagem anexa.

Fiz um código abaixo que não quebrou a linha quando muda para 2018

**TABELA**

```
CREATE TABLE `clientes_vendas` (
  `codigo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cliente_cnpj` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `codigo_cliente` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `codigo_repre` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `valor` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `dia` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `mes` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `ano` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `data` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**CÓDIGO**

```
while:                         

  if ($ano_atual2==0) {
      $ano_atual2 = $ano;
  }  
  $pula_linha="\n";

  if ( $ano != $ano_atual2 )  :
      $ano_atual2 = $ano;
      $dadosTXT2 = "$pula_linha$nome_repre;$mes;$ano$pula_linha";
      $arraDados[] = $dadosTXT2;
      $soma=0;
  endif;

   @$soma +=  $row['valor'];
   $somaConvert = number_format($soma,2,",",".");
   $dadosTXT2 = "$cnpj_cliente;$nome_cliente;$nome_repre;$mes;$ano;$valor$pula_linha";
   $arraDados[] = $dadosTXT2;

endwhile; 

$fp = fopen($csv, 'a');
$escreve1 = fwrite($fp,   utf8_decode($header));

foreach ($arraDados as $file) {
    $escreve2 = fwrite($fp,  $file);
}

fclose($fp);
```

**RESULTADO ESPERADO: Exibir as SOMAS da vendas de clientes lado a lado EXEMPLO: AGOSTO 2017 , AGOSTO 2018, SETEMBRO 2017- SETEMBRO 2018 mas começando normalmente de janeiro**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: todos os cliente possuem cnpjs únicos ou podem se repetir? ou existe outro índice de id único na sua tabela?

Comment: apenas o codigo é único AnthraxisBR

Comment: O que eu não entendi é que na imagem do resultado esperado mostra, NA MESMA LINHA => `1, 2017, valor` - `1, 2018, valor` - `2, 2017, valor`. É isso que você quer? Porque?

Comment: Qual a relação? Não entendi. `O primeiro é o mês de janeiro de 2017, depois é janeiro 2018 e depois é fevereiro de 2017. A logo abaixo começa com janeiro de 2017, depois janeiro de 2018(outro valor), e fevereiro de 2018.`

Comment: @denis,você já pensou em fazer um tratamento similar ao que você está fazendo ao ano?o código é único por cliente,código vai começar em zero,na 1ª interação faz o preenchimento da 1ª linha com as informações por ex: $linha=$cnpj_cliente;...;$mes;$ano;$valor;
na interação seguinte se o código for igual você continua concatenando só os dados de mês,ano,valor, $linha.=$mes;$ano;$valor; e assim vai, até vir um código diferente,com isso $linha .=$pular_linha e armazena no array de saída.inicia novamente o $linha, atualizando o codigo ,colocando o "cabeçalho" como na primeira interação e etc..

Comment: @AndreiCoelho Coelho eu editei a imagem aquela não estava clara ! o cabeçalho não precisa apenas os resultados

Comment: Agora eu entendi!

Comment: Vou analisar @MarcusItalo Italo obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para responder a sua pergunta eu tive que criar outras tabelas que não foram informadas para obter o `nome_representante` e o `nome_cliente`. E para fazer testes eu criei alguns registros diversos, veja:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Coloquei como opcional o valor de entrada do inicio do ano e do fim do ano a ser analisado, pois pode ser que você queira realizar um filtro. Veja a linha abaixo:

```
$anoInicio = "2017";
$anoFim = "2018";
```

Por fim, criei o código com base no seu. Repare que o `select` está ordenando, primeiro pelo mês, depois pelo código do cliente e depois pelo ano. Deste modo você conseguirá o resultado esperado.

```
    $anoInicio = "2017";
    $anoFim = "2018";

    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT ano, mes, 
        (
            SELECT nome_cliente FROM cliente 
            WHERE cliente.codigo_cliente = clientes_vendas.codigo_cliente 
        ) AS 'nome_cliente', 
        (
            SELECT nome_representante FROM representante 
            WHERE representante.codigo_representante = clientes_vendas.codigo_representante 
            GROUP BY representante.codigo_representante
        ) AS 'nome_representante', 
        SUM(valor) AS 'total' FROM clientes_vendas 
        WHERE ano >= '$anoInicio' AND ano <= '$anoFim' 
        GROUP BY mes, codigo_cliente, ano ORDER BY codigo_cliente, mes, ano ASC"
        );

    $arraDados = array();
    $strTmpCliente = "";
    $mes = array('', 'Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'); // formatador dos meses
    $x = 1;


    while($dados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

        if($strTmpCliente != $dados['nome_cliente']){
            $strTmpCliente = $dados['nome_cliente'];
            $arraDados[$strTmpCliente] = array();
            $arraDados[$strTmpCliente]['nome'] = $dados['nome_cliente'];
            $arraDados[$strTmpCliente]['representante'] = $dados['nome_representante'];
        }

        $strMesAno = $mes[$dados['mes']]."_".$dados['ano'];
        $arraDados[$strTmpCliente][$strMesAno] = number_format($dados['total'],2,",",".");

    }


    $header = "Cliente;Representante;";
    $mesAtual = 1;
    $anoAtual = (int)$anoInicio;

    $arrayDatas = array();

    for($x = 0; $x < 24; $x++){

        $data = $mes[$mesAtual]."_".$anoAtual;
        $arrayDatas[] = $data;
        $header .= str_replace("_", "'",$data).";";

        $alteraMes = $x % 2 == 0 ? false : true;
        if($alteraMes){
            $mesAtual++;
            $anoAtual = $anoInicio;
            continue;
        }
        $anoAtual = $anoFim;
    }
    $header = substr($header, 0, -1);
    $header .= "\n";

    $strDados = array();

    foreach($arraDados as $cliente ){

        $strTmp = $cliente['nome'].";".$cliente['representante'].";";
        for($i = 0; $i < count($arrayDatas); $i++){
            $data = $arrayDatas[$i];
            if(isset($cliente[$data])){
                $strTmp .= $cliente[$data].";";
                continue;
            }
            $strTmp .= "-;";
        }

        $strTmp = substr($strTmp, 0, -1);
        $strTmp .= "\n";
        $strDados[] = $strTmp;

    }

    $csv = "arquivo.csv";

    // escreve o cabeçalho
    $fp1 = fopen($csv, 'w');
    fwrite($fp1, $header);
    fclose($fp1);

    // escreve o resultado
    $fp2 = fopen($csv, 'a');
    foreach ($strDados as $file) {
        fwrite($fp2,  $file);
    }
    fclose($fp2);
```

O arquivo gerado ficou assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**EDIT**

Eu reparei que na **[imagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTZ1d.jpg)** que você postou que alguns meses ficaram sem vendas. Fui fazer o teste no meu código e, como eu imaginava, deu erro. Pois os valores eram preenchidos sequencialmente.

Eu alterei o código e agora está funcionando corretamente. Aproveitei para inserir o `number_format` que você está usando. O resultado foi esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**EDIT 2**

Altere essa parte que irá funcionar:

```
           if($strTmpCliente != $dados['nome_cliente']){
                $strTmpCliente = $dados['nome_cliente'];
                $arraDados[$strTmpCliente] = array();
                $arraDados[$strTmpCliente]['nome'] = $dados['nome_cliente'];
                $arraDados[$strTmpCliente]['representante'] = $dados['nome_representante'];
            }

            //---> o erro estava aqui
            $dadosMes = (int)$dados['mes']; // aqui ele transforma em inteiro 
            $strMesAno = $mes[$dadosMes]."_".$dados['ano']; // aqui ele grava a strinmg corretamente
            $arraDados[$strTmpCliente][$strMesAno] = number_format($dados['total'],2,",",".");
```

Comment: aparentemente seu código funcionou mas só começa preencher os valores depois de Out'2017 sendo que existe vendas nos meses anteriores, estou analisando para ver encontro o porque depois te retorno!

Comment: acho que porque na minha tabela os meses são gravados em VARCHAR e com 0 tipo 01,02,03 e sua variável está $mesAtual =1 estou a verificar .....

Comment: veja como está ! @AndreiCoelho https://codeshare.io/aJAJMK

Comment: mudei para $mesAtual = '01'; e começou pegando de JAN'2017 e JAN'2018 depois já pula para Out'2017 novamente ... link atualizado com as outras duas tabelas que só são para pegar os nomes https://codeshare.io/aJAJMK

Comment: @denis pode ser... Vou fazer outros testes.

Comment: @denis o erro era exatamente esse. Acabei de alterar. Está no EDIT 2

Comment: @denis conseguiu?

Comment: Consegui era a formatação para inteiro mesmo ! Resposta perfeita Muito obrigado !

Comment: @denis Tranquilo! Abraço!

Answer (score 4):

```
$codigo_cliente = 0;
$pula_linha="\n";
while:                         

  if ($ano_atual2==0) {
      $ano_atual2 = $ano;
  }
  if ( $ano != $ano_atual2 )  :
      $ano_atual2 = $ano;
      $dadosTXT2 = "$pula_linha$nome_repre;$mes;$ano$pula_linha";
      $arraDados[] = $dadosTXT2;
      $soma=0;
  endif;

  if ($codigo_cliente == 0) {
      $codigo_cliente  = $row['codigo'];
      $linha = "$cnpj_cliente;$nome_cliente;$nome_repre;";
  }

  @$soma +=  $row['valor'];
   $somaConvert = number_format($soma,2,",",".");

  if ( $row['codigo']!= $codigo_cliente)  {
       $codigo_cliente  = $row['codigo'];
       $linha .= $pula_linha;
       $arraDados[] = $linha;
       $linha = "$cnpj_cliente;$nome_cliente;$nome_repre;$mes;$ano;$valor";
  }
  else{
    $linha .= "$mes;$ano;$valor;";
  }

endwhile; 

$fp = fopen($csv, 'a');
$escreve1 = fwrite($fp,   utf8_decode($header));

foreach ($arraDados as $file) {
    $escreve2 = fwrite($fp,  $file);
}

fclose($fp);
```

Espero ter ajudado ou pelo menos chegado perto.

Comment: +1 por ter tirado o `$pula_linha` do loop

Comment: Uma dica: por que ao invés de fazer essa trabalheira toda na mão, vocês não usam a função [`fputcsv`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fputcsv.php)?